# Neo4j community edition uses AllNodesSan instead of NodeByLabelScan

Tags: indexing, neo4j, cypher

I am using Neo4j community edition 4.4.11 to build an application.

I have created some Image nodes in my database and performed the following query.
I was expecting neo4j to use NodeByLabelScan

```
PROFILE MATCH (n:Image)  RETURN n LIMIT 25
```

However, it scanned all database to find Image nodes...

[image]

Is this supposed?

Thank you.

can Someone tell me why this happened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even with index on :Image, it will do a nodescan because you are not using an index.

Try this, if you have Image.name that exists.

```
 create index imageNameIdx for (i:Image) on i.name
```

Then

```
 PROFILE MATCH (i:Image) WHERE i.name = <something> RETURN n
```

It will show you that it is using that index (NodeIndexSeek)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i just solved the problem now. It was because I had removed the native indexes of Neo4j (i am so stupid).

Comment: If you execute the query "SHOW INDEXES" you will see 2 native indexes that have id 1 and id 2. NodeByLabelScan is run based on them. Now i can search for Image nodes without doing AllNodesScan.